# Xcode Buildtime Error: 'Unable to load contents of file list: '.../Info.plist' (in target 'xxxx')

Tags: ios, xcode, info.plist

Xcode started throwing this error in a project today, and I'm having trouble figuring out what it means and how to troubleshoot it, and it's not coming up in any searches. It happens immediately after trying to build to a device (no scripts compile, etc):

**error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Users/.../Products/Debug-appletvos/myapp.app/Info.plist' (in target 'myapp')**

Full log below, (note I've replaced build folder with ... for brevity)

```
Showing Recent Messages

Prepare build
note: Using new build systemnote: Planning buildnote: Constructing build description

Build system information
error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Users/.../Products/Debug-appletvos/myapp.app/Info.plist' (in target 'myapp')


Build failed    3/5/19, 3:09 PM    0.2 seconds
```

Things I've tried so far:

- Restarting Xcode
- Restarting Computer
- 'Product' > 'Clean Build Folder'
- Manually deleting everything in Build folder
- Re-download repository on the same computer (same issue)
- Re-download repository on a different computer (same issue)
- reverting to a previous commit that was working (same issue)
- `plutil Info.plist` responds with `Info.plist: OK`

Other items of note:

- Project uses Cocoapods
- Project utilizes custom C++ code
- The only file list in the `Info.plist` file is a list of 2 custom fonts, but those are showing up ok in the Xcode project browser (not red).

If anyone has encountered this before and has a fix, or has any other suggestions for troubleshooting I would greatly appreciate it, thanks!

Answer (score 119, accepted):

In my case, I just fixed below

1. Open terminal under project folder
2. `pod deintegrate`
3. `sudo gem install cocoapods-clean`
4. `pod clean`
5. Open the project and delete (if it's still there) the “Pods” folder that should be red
6. `pod setup` (This may take some time)
7. `pod install`

Comment: I've tried on Xcode 11.3.1 and It solves the problem. Thanks.

Comment: I tried it with Xcode 12.3 & working awesome. Thanks for a awesome answer.

Comment: Worked with Xcode 13.2.1 Thanks!

Comment: Worked with Xcode 14.0, many thanks!

Comment: in my case after this script had to issue

pod install --repo-update

Answer (score 24):

I fix this in this way:

1、Go to your project's target, -> Build Phases -> Embed Pods Frameworks

2、check the input files and input file lists, Output files, and output file lists.

3、move dir from input file lists to input files, and output file lists to output files

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: And in `[CP] Copy Pods Resources`

Comment: @Randall Wang Thanks a lot,But tell me one thing why this happened?

Answer (score 16):

I realised after a while that my colleague has updated cocoapods to the latest version, so what I did was just

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

And that did the trick! :)

Comment: Yes, upgrading to 1.7.2 and then `pod install` again worked.

Comment: I didn't know why, but I saw this and realized it. Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

Finally figured this out, posting here so others googling can find it.

It was an issue with a build script that used the 'Input File Lists' option, removing and re-adding the script fixed the issue.

- Nav to Target
- 'Build Phases' tab
- 'Run Script' phase
- make notes of what's there, remove it
- re-run to make sure things work
- re-add the script (and content under 'Input File Lists')

Comment: In my case, I had added the output file path to the 'Input File list' while attempting to add a framework using Carthage, instead of adding it to 'Output files' where it belongs.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that you have added path to `Input File Lists` instead of `Input Files`

Answer (score 4):

In my case

```
pod deintegrate
pod install
```

was enough

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I just fixed below

1- Go to your project's target, -> Build Phases -> Delete **[CP] Copy Pods Resources**.
2- `pod deintegrate`.
3- `pod install`.

Answer (score 2):

No need to deintegrate pods and install again. Just run

```html
pod install
```

It will create necessary files for new configurations.

Answer (score 1):

First, you work:

- Delete the `.xcworkspace` file
- Delete the `Podfile.lock` file and `Pods/ directory`
- Keep the `Podfile`
- Rerun `pod install`

`If the error still occurs`, you need to add include .xcconfig path for CocoaPods in your .xcconfig files by prepending an #include statement like the following: `#include “Pods/[path .xccofig file in Terminal”`

Example:

I have two environments `Stag` and `Production`

- After I run the pod file in Terminal. You’ll see in Terminal that CocoaPods did not set the configuration since we already set custom configurations. CocoaPods provides a link to be included in each

[image: message from Teminal]

- Open `.xcworkspace` file and select `.xcconfig` file

[image: step by step stag enviroment]

[image: step by step production enviroment]

Finally, `Cmd` + `Shift` + `K` and `run project`

Good luck!!!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Xcode was using a Build Configuration that didn't exist anymore. Going to 'edit scheme...' and selecting a valid scheme fixed it for me.