# 'db/version_edit.h' file not found - Xcode 12.4 archive only error

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, leveldb

```
#include "db/version_edit.h"
```

I'm getting 'db/version_edit.h' file not found on the above line of this file after I tapped to Archive.

```
Pods/leveldb-library/version_edit.cc
```

Is there any way to overcome this issue? I have tried many pod deintegrate and install / updates like below answer but It didn't help me.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56125602/6135652

I also had 'Unable to load contents of file list: '…/Info.plist' error too from Firebase/Analytics pod, but I have just discarded it and I saw only this 'db/version_edit.h' file not found error now.

Comment: What version of CocoaPods and Firebase?

Comment: @PaulBeusterien Hi, CocoaPods: Pod 1.10.1 - for Firebase I tested both 7.5.0 (latest) and also 7.3.0 too. But I'm still stuck with that.

Comment: It might be the result of something else in another pod or the project settings doing something to a search path or another build setting.

Comment: @PaulBeusterien Okay, I will try to investigate for adding pods step by step after deintegrate all. Maybe It will help me to find about which one is. When I checked search paths and configs, it looks good for me.

Comment: SG - I would suggest reviewing any bold, non-default options in the Build Settings of the deintegrated Xcode project build settings.

Comment: I had something similar and the link you included in the question did help me. Tx. I know this was a year ago but I hope things worked out for you.